# Current state of the art for holographic displays?

Tags: hardware

In another thread I was asking about independent arcade system development, and partly it was because I'm interested in using available 3D holographic technology for the displays.

I saw one which involved a rotating mirror at very high speeds, so that's probably not going to be too feasible (I'd hate to think of what happens when something goes wrong).

However, I looked around for videos from trade shows, and I found this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vl0EIngM-RA

But information is scarce, and I'm led to believe it's just using mirrors and reflections, and does not convey true 3D depth like the one using rotating mirrors at high speed:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKCUGQ-uo8c

So yeah, does anyone know if there's something better available today?

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to ignore the hyperbolic commentary. This is a new display technology that uses lasers to ignite the very air into a little ball of plasma, creating an amazing dot matrix free floating 3D display.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfVS-npfVuY